# PXE Boot and Fully Automated Install?

Tags: system-installation, pxe

I am trying to set up a PXE environment to automate Ubuntu installs.   I have a PXE server running with DHCP and [Bionic netboot images](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/bionic/)

I can boot a bare box, load the menu and install interactively just fine.    I want a complete hands-off installation and I have been trying to deploy a correct preseed.cfg environment.

I grabbed the example [preseed.cfg from here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt) and I'm using python -m SimpleHTTPServer to make it available.  In the file ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/txt.cfg I add the line:

```
append vga=788 initrd=ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz auto preseed/url=http://192.168.0.100:8000/preseed.cfg
```

I do see that the the preseed.cfg file is requested via the web server (status 200) but only after the questions about keyboard configuration, network interface and ubuntu repos.  Also, none of the subsequent questions seem to be skipped, I'm still asked everything.

Again my goal is a 100% hands-off generic ubuntu installation.  Am I on the right track and I just need to fix the structure of my preseed.cfg file or am I way off base?